# How to setup Amazon EC2 Instance as Subversione Server

Tags: svn, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I write in this forum because I need a versioning server to sharing source code and working in a team on a project. What I thought is an Amazon EC2 instance that runs as a Subversion server. 
Is it possible for you? 
I have never work with EC2 and I do not know hao to get an EC2 instance, how to install Subversione and how to get a public IP to that server, in other words I have no experience on EC2 in generale.

Could anybody help me?
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bitbucket and then deploy your changes to the Amazon server.

Use this link to learn how to install it: https://bitbucket.org/icosahedron/git-sync-ec2

Comment: Ok. You are saying to install in the EC2 Server instance Bitbucket...and of course a web server right?